# Java HashTable null pointer exception

Tags: java

i am building a server to sends questions to clients and then receive answer from them, but when i send a question to a client i want to make it as unaviable for sending again for one hour, i mean after i send a question to client , i want for one hour that question will never sends to any other clients,

```
static Hashtable<Integer, List<Integer>> unavialbeQuestions =
new Hashtable<Integer, List<Integer>>();
```

the key is the clientID, the value is list of the IDs of questions that will never send to that client in one hour, this function i used to make question as unaivalble

```
public void setUnavialbeQuestion(final String cellName, final int questionID) {
        List<Integer> cells = getCellsIntersectedWithCell(cellName);
        int cellID = getCellID(cellName);
        cells.add(cellID);
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++) {
            if (unavialbeQuestions.containsKey(cellID)) {
                unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).add(questionID);
            } else {
                List<Integer> lll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                lll.add(questionID);
                unavialbeQuestions.put(cellID, lll);
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    f(cellName, questionID);
                }
            }, 1000 * 120);
        }
    }
```

see the function `f()` that will fired after one hour (in my demo just 2mins), here is the problem, i got null pointer exception when executing the `f()` function:

```
protected void f(String cellName, int questionDI) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Integer> cells = getCellsIntersectedWithCell(cellName);
        int cellID = getCellID(cellName);
        cells.add(cellID);

        for(int i=0;i<cells.size();i++){
            int index = unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).indexOf(questionDI);
            unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).remove(index);
        }
    }
```

the exception on the `index` parameter,
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: would help to have the NPE stack trace

Comment: It would help to know what line the NPE occurred on.  The obvious answer is "you're dereferencing something that's null", but without line numbers it's impossible to say whether `getCellsIntersectedWithCell()` returned `null`, or `unavialbeQuestions.get()`, or `cells.get(i)`, or something else...

Comment: @assylias i didn't got u, what are you asking me about?

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle the exception on the `index` parameter

Comment: When you receive the NPE (NullPointerException), it shows you the line on which it is thrown - that is an important information because you know where the problem is.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle no no everything is right with that statements, but the exeption on the `index`

Comment: @assylias the exception on the `index` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't check that the returned list is not null here:

```
unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).indexOf(questionDI);
```

and here:

```
unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).remove(index);
```

And you use different keys for your map here:

```
if (unavialbeQuestions.containsKey(cellID)) {
```

and here:

```
unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).add(questionID);
```

(and your code is not thread-safe, also)

Comment: `unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).indexOf(questionDI);` for sure it is not null, because i add it in the `setUnavialbeQuestion`,

Comment: the thread will never fire if it is null, check the loop, the tread is begin working in the loop

Comment: Read my answer: you set `cellID` in the map, but get `cells.get(i)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what is the solution please?

Comment: To thread-safety? Mark the whole method as `synchronized` and use a `HashMap` instead of `HashTable`.

Comment: @JBNizet i will check the cells

Comment: Both `f()` and `setUnavialbeQuestion()` must be synchronized of course.

Comment: @JBNizet yes u right, the cells is null, thank you very much, but now how can i make that functions is syncronize? and have i to change any thing in the server?

Comment: By adding the `synchronized` keyword to their declaration: `protected synchronized void f(...)`. You shouldn't do anything related to threads if you don't even know what synchronization is. At least read the Java concurrency tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1):

unavialbeQuestions or cells list may be **null**. If you are trying to access it's method, it will throw **NullPointerException**.

Comment: the exception in the `index` variable

Comment: @Totti Just print unavialbeQuestions before the statement unavialbeQuestions.get(cells.get(i)).indexOf(questionDI);